# How can i get Creation date of image while file upload in javascript

Tags: javascript

i search many things on this and try but all the options are return the modified date of file , but actually i want original Creation date of the file While file uploading

```
var reader = new FileReader();

var files  = e.target.files;
var created_date = files[0].lastModifiedDate;
var name = files[0].name;
```

But this Line Is returning `var created_date = files[0].lastModifiedDate;`
 Modified Date Of File
Please suggest Some options.....

Comment: this all codes are Returning the Modification and changed date time of the files and what i want is creation date @RGraham

Comment: From the answer: *You can not get the creation date*